Visual studio code metrics calculation error
When I tried to calculate code metrics for my visual studio WPF application I noticed that it won't work. It showed error message: One or more projects were skipped. Code metrics are available only for C# and Visual Basic projects that are not Web Site projects or shared projects.
I am not creating or using anything related to Web site project. I checked visual studio forums, and there was a few people that had the same issue. Visual studio answered to them that they prioritize problems that are popular. So they just ignored it. I tried everything, reinstalling, clearing cache, everything you can think. I noticed one thing. After deleting hidden .vs folder in my project it code metrics magically started working, but only for couple of times after all files in .vs are automatically recreated.

I found the problem in the .vs folder. It was a file .suo. It stores information about user interface that you set up in the visual studio. So I started to playing with settings untill I found one that fixed the issue. It was the "Reopen documents on solution load", after I disabled it, everything started working normally.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General. Uncheck "Reopen documents on solution load" and "Track active item in Solution Explorer".
